# Heapsort with a selectable amount of children

Tags: c++, algorithm, heapsort

Im trying to write some code that could sort an array using heapsort. The heap have two children right now but i want the user to be able to choose the amount of children in the heap(d in the function heapsort).

Question: How do i make the function heapsort able to recieve a number (d) from the user and sort the array with heapsort with that amount of children?

```
template <typename T>
void heapify(T arr[], int n, int i) {

    int biggest = i;
    int leftChild = 2 * i + 1;
    int rightChild = 2 * i + 2;

    if (leftChild < n && arr[leftChild] > arr[biggest])
    {
        biggest = leftChild;
    }

    if (rightChild < n && arr[rightChild] > arr[biggest]) {
        biggest = rightChild;
    }

    if (biggest != i) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[biggest]);

        heapify(arr, n, biggest);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void heapsort(T arr[], int n, int d)
{
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(arr, n, i);
    }

    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);

        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }

}
```

Comment: *but i want the user to be able to choose the amount of children in the heap* -- `int d; std::cin >> d; ... heapsort(arr, n, d);`.  Otherwise I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: Yeah sorry for being a little unclear but what im after is the algorithm inside the function

Comment: Maybe you should revisit your design.  A properly built binary heap doesn't need this extra information.  For example, the standard [std::sort_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort_heap) function doesn't need this -- all that's required is the array (in terms of start of the array, and end of the array), as long as the array has the properties of a heap.

Comment: In other words, I should be able to take your array you claim is a heap, and call `std::sort_heap(arr, arr + n);` and it should work (assuming a max-heap), or `sort_heap(arr, arr + n, std::greater<int>()):` if it is a min-heap.  If it doesn't work, then what you are claiming is a binary heap is not a binary heap (or one that was not properly built).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you made it so easy:

```C++
template <typename T>
void heapify(T arr[], int n, int d, int i) {

    int biggest = i;
    int childrenStart = d * i + 1;
    int childrenEnd = childrenStart + d;

    if (childrenEnd > n) {
        childrenEnd = n;
    }

    for (int child = childrenStart; child < childrenEnd; ++child) {
        if (arr[child] > arr[biggest]) {
            biggest = child;
        }
    }

    if (biggest != i) {
        swap(arr[i], arr[biggest]);
        heapify(arr, n, d, biggest);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void heapsort(T arr[], int n, int d)
{
    if (n<=0) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = (n-2) / d; i >= 0; i--) {
        heapify(arr, n, d, i);
    }

    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        swap(arr[0], arr[i]);
        heapify(arr, i, d, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: That said, there is no way that following pointers all over the heap is better than the usual optimized array approach.